# redirect a process to file AND redirect its time to a file

Tags: bash, redirect

I'd like to redirect the time of a process to a file, and the process itself redirects to a file.  Here's what I've tried:

```
time &> ltime.txt echo | ls -l > ls-l.txt
```

Both files (`ltime.txt` and `ls-l.txt`) are created, but `ltime.txt` is empty.

`time` still outputs to the screen,
which is fine in my case,
but I expected it to *not* do that because of the `&>`:

```
    real    0m0.034s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.004s
```

(All that I know about this came from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you're right; echo extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're getting bitten by the `time` that's built-in to the shell? Try this:

```
/usr/bin/time ls -l > ls-l.txt 2> ltime.txt
```

From `man time`:

```
   Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
   the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.
```

[Updated to add]

Apparently the location of `time` isn't totally standard. For a one-off use (and for general info) `which time` will tell you where it is. For a portable script you can say `command time ...`. (`command` is a shell built-in that tells the shell to ignore built-ins.)

Comment: That worked in os x and in ubuntu, but not in debian 7.1 wheezy.  I get both files, but the ltime.txt file contains "-bash: /usr/bin/time: No such file or directory" I found time.h in /usr/include/time.h (amongst other places) but I can't seem to find "time".  The locate command outputs hundreds of entries... any suggestions?

Comment: If you're stuck with the builtin, see my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `command time ls -l > ls-l.txt 2> ltime.txt`, the `command` keyword will find the external command if it installed in a standard location.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{ time ls -l > ls-l.txt ; }  &> ltime.txt
```

The curly braces capture the output even with the builtin.

Comment: This is what it gives on my Mac :`$ { time ls -l > ls-l.txt ; }  &> ltime.txt 
$ cat ltime.txt 

real 0m0.097s
user 0m0.002s
sys 0m0.009s
`